# send outlook email in nested view using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code that send two email reminder to user. The code attached below worked perfectly. My problem is that, I want the second reminder to be nested from the first reminder.

```
'create session
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim newMail As Object
Dim Emailto, sendfrom As String

'create reply
Dim convo As Conversation
Dim convoItem
Dim entry As String

For J = ws.Cells(5, "C").Value To ws.Cells(6, "C").Value

'get value from combo box
If combovalue = "First Reminder" Then
'MsgBox combovalue

'set a reply
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutNS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
entry = ws.Cells(J, "G")
Set mail = OutNS.GetItemFromID(entry) 'get handle on mail item
Set convo = mail.GetConversation 'get handle on existing conversation
Set convoItem = convo.GetRootItems(1) 'get convo root item
Set newMail = convoItem.Reply 'new email as reply to convo
Emailto = ws.Cells(J, "D").Value
sendfrom = "email"

On Error Resume Next
With newMail
.SendUsingAccount = sendfrom
.To = Emailto
.Subject = "Test"
.VotingOptions = "Acknowledge;"
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "Body here"
.Send 'or use .Display to open Outlook's new message window before sending
ws.Cells(J, "T").Value = Date
End With

On Error GoTo 0
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set newMail = Nothing
End If

If combovalue = "Second Reminder" Then
'MsgBox ("Correct")
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutNS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
entry = ws.Cells(J, "Z")
Set mail = OutNS.GetItemFromID(entry) 'get handle on mail item
Set convo = mail.GetConversation 'get handle on existing conversation
Set convoItem = convo.GetRootItems(1) 'get convo root item
Set newMail = convoItem.Reply 'new email as reply to convo
Emailto = ws.Cells(J, "D").Value
sendfrom = "email"

On Error Resume Next
With newMail
.SendUsingAccount = sendfrom
.To = Emailto
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Test"
.VotingOptions = "Acknowledge;"
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "Body here"
.Send 'or use .Display to open Outlook's new message window before sending
ws.Cells(J, "U").Value = Date
End With

On Error GoTo 0
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set newMail = Nothing
End If
Next J
```

the first reminder is nested on top of parent email, but for second reminder, instead of nested on top of first reminder and parent email, it was send as a separate mail nested on top of parent email. how can i solve this??

*EDIT*
Example:

1.parent email entry ID AABJ23

2.first reminder will reply to parent email by setting the entryID to AABJ23
then I will get a new entry ID for the first reminder after i sent the email, ABBJ54

3.second reminder will reply to first reminder email by setting the entry ID to ABBJ54

Comment: You reply to `convo.GetRootItems(1)` in both cases so the result is the same. To get deeper in the conversation is more complex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256143/set-all-mail-items-in-an-outlook-conversation-to-read-using-vba You might consider saving the entryID of the first reminder and creating the second reminder from that  rather than attempting to find it in the conversation.

Comment: Hi Niton, I already did as you suggest and I still get the same result. I edited my question with the example. As you can see from my code, the entry id value is different from first and second reminder. I have another macro that will retrieved all the entryID in my specified mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the two different entryIDs to retrieve `convo.GetRootItems(1)` which is the originating item.

The entryIDs already identify the mail you want to reply to.

```
If comboValue = "First Reminder" Then

    entry = ws.Cells(j, "G") ' entryID of the parent mail
    Set Mail = OutNS.GetItemFromID(entry) 'get handle on parent mail
    Set newMail = Mail.reply 'new email as reply to parent mail

End If

If comboValue = "Second Reminder" Then

    entry = ws.Cells(j, "Z") ' entryID of first reminder
    Set Mail = OutNS.GetItemFromID(entry) 'get handle on first reminder item
    Set newMail = Mail.reply 'new email as reply to first reminder

End If
```

Comment: Hi Niton, so, I dont need to use .GetRootItem(1) for both first and second reminder?

Comment: Hi Niton. YOU ARE MY LIFE SAVER! I couldnt tell you how grateful I am to you! Thank you very much! But can you explain more on the .GetRootItem(1)? I am a novice in all of this. Thank you again.